# Prove that if $\log{f(n)} \in O(g(n))$ then $f(n)\in O(3^{g(n)})$

Tags: asymptotics

> Let $\mathcal{F}=\{f|f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}^+\}$
>   $$\forall f\in\mathcal{F}: \log{f(n)} \in O(g(n))\implies f(n)\in O(3^{g(n)}).$$

How to prove this? I thought about first showing that $$g(n) \in O(3^{g(n)})$$ Then $$\log{f(n)} \in O(f(n))$$ but that doesn't necessarily mean $$f(n)\in O(3^{g(n)}).$$ does it?

Update: This is a false statement, counter-example: f(n) = $4^x$, g(n) = x

Comment: No that is the opposite implication.

Comment: Not true. $f/g$ bounded doesn't imply $e^f/e^g=e^{f-g}$ is bounded.

Comment: Are you saying the statement is false? Could you please explain I don't quite understand, thanks

Comment: Yes, the statement is false. Try $f(x)=4^x$ and $g(x)=x$. More generally, $O(e^f)\ne e^{O(f)}$

Comment: You could also say $e^{O(f)}=(O(1))^f$.

Answer (score 2):

Since the exponential function is  strictly increasing, it preserves inequalities when applied to both sides of an inequality so:
$$
\log(f(n))\leq c\cdot g(n)\iff f(n)\leq \operatorname e^{c\cdot g(n)}=\left(\operatorname e^c\right)^{g(n)}
$$
and this is only $O(3^{g(n)})$ if a constant $c\leq\log(3)$ will work.